# My inadyn is working, but my no-ip hostnames repeatedly expire

Tags: linux, dynamic-dns, noip

I have a few domain names on no-ip.me . I used the inadyn client, available as part of my Linux distribution (Debian Stretch). `/var/log/messages` shows me that it's working (forced update every ~40,000 seconds).

Still, every once in a while I get an email warning me that a domain will expire unless I manually update it on the site.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Or are no-ip.me just being abusive of their gratis users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. The old trick used to be to temporarily change your host to a dummy IP and then change it back to a legitimate IP. This would cause the [API](http://www.noip.com/integrate/response) to respond with "good" and you were set for another month (I even implemented this in my [fork](https://github.com/mdmower/bash-no-ip-updater) of AntonioCS's bash script). The trick doesn't work anymore and [manual login and verification](http://www.noip.com/support/faq/frequently-asked-questions/why-did-my-free-hostname-expire-or-get-deleted/) is now required.

Answer (score 1):

No-IP basically treats unchanged IP's as a non-update.  Even if you set it to send an update every 10 seconds, No-IP only considers it an update if the IP changes.

> nochg IP_ADDRESS  Success IP address is current, no update performed. Followed by a space and the IP address that it is currently set to.

[No-IP API Guide](http://www.noip.com/integrate/response)

As an aside:  I tried to make a quick and dirty inadyn client that took my IP, added 0.0.0.1 to it (192.168.1.100 becomes 192.168.1.101), updated NoIP with that, waited 15 seconds, then send another update with my actual IP so that NoIP would see a changed IP and update - didn't have much success with it and gave up.

Comment: That's rather innane. Does that mean I'm supposed to update to a false IP just to then update to the correct one, just to avoid expiration? ... unbelievable. Did you try to talk to the No-IP people by any chance?

Comment: @einpoklum We must of been thinking on the same brainwave...as far as I can tell, yes.  I'm not a fan of it either.  I'm on Cox and even though I have a "dynamic" ip, I'm thinking it's tied to my modem's MAC as I get the same IP even on power loss, reboots, etc.  That's why I said to heck with it and gave up on NoIP and just added a subdomain to one of my domains that I own and pointed it to my public IP.